# RecyclerView with ImageView and differents Activities

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview

What I have: A RecyclerView with pictures of places like bars, cofee stores, etc.

What I want: That when you click on one of these images I show you the info of the selected place

My question: How can i set the `OnCLickListener` for the third picture for example?

Many people have told me to do it on my "`onBindViewHolder()`" method, but it doesn't allow me to implement the "`startActivity`" so i can pass to the "`Intent`" Please, if you can explain with code it would be great, I am not good programming yet, so I would really appreciate

My Adapter

```
public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares;
private View.OnClickListener listener;

public AdapterDatos(ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listaLugares) {
    listalugares = listaLugares;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {//esto es lo que hacereferencia al xml donde vamos a meter la info
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);//aqui le asignamos el valor del view al viewHolder
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {// este metodo es el que se encarga de establecer la conexion entre el adaptador y la clase Viewholder ( a la cual le asignamos el xml)
    holder.etiLugares.setText(listalugares.get(position).getLugares());// asi se asignan los textos
    holder.Foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());//asi se asignan las fotos


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {//este metodo va a decir el tamaño del viewHolder, en este caso de tamaño del array listalugares
    return listalugares.size();//se hace asi
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    if(listener!= null){
        listener.onClick(view);
   }
```

}

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView etiLugares;
    ImageView Foto;
    Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        etiLugares = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);//esto hace referencia a los elementos donde queremos meter la info
        Foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);

    }
}
```

}

My Java class

```
 public class foodAndGo extends Activity {

ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares;
RecyclerView recyclerLugares;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_and_go);

    listalugares = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerLugares = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerID);
    recyclerLugares.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    llenarNombres();

    AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(listalugares);
    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Seleccion"+listalugares.get(recyclerLugares.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getLugares(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(foodAndGo.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
  recyclerLugares.setAdapter(adapter);

}



private void llenarNombres() {
    listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Restaurantes", R.drawable.carnemejor));
    listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Bares", R.drawable.beers));
    listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Cafeterías",R.drawable.desayunosmejor));
    listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Pizzerias",R.drawable.pizzaamejor));
    listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Favoritos",R.drawable.favoritosmejo));


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `foodAndGo` activity change,

`AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(listalugares);` to `AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(listalugares,foodAndGo.this);`

and inside adapter class add this

```
private Context context;
public AdapterDatos(ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listaLugares,Context context) {
this.context=context;
listalugares = listaLugares;
}
```

Now, you can call startactivity in adapter's `onBindViewHolder` like this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: OMG!!! it actually worked!!! thank you so much, i am new on the site, tell me what can i do to reward you, i really appreciate the time you spend on my question. Again thank you so much, i will wait for your answer about how to reward you on the site :)